# send post request with dynamic data

Tags: objective-c, post, request, uitextfield

good afternoon
I have been looking but I haven't found anything similar

I am starting with Xcode and objective C please you be patient with me

I want do this

I have a text field intended to be a search box

currently I send a POST request programmatically and the parameters are static

well,  I want dynamic parameters

the content of the text field is dynamic parameters

how do I can do it?

I have also a button for sending the request

help please

this is code of the request

```
NSString *Post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"query=deporte"];

    NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.laleo.com/ebooks_android/ebooks_search_json.php"];

    NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [PostData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [Request setURL:Url];
    [Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [Request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [Request setHTTPBody:PostData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    //NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                       error:&error];
```

The text field already is available through of @synthesize palabra;

The button is in the graphical interface

Comment: Post the code of your request

Comment: already I post the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create an action handler for your button. Use Interface Builder for that. Also you'll need to connect the outlet for the textfield with your viewcontroller's class. Then, just take a text value from your textfield and send it into the request. If you need to know how you can receive a text from the textfield, just use this:

```
NSString *text = _textField.text;
```